# PHP Json_Encode strange characters?

Tags: php, json

I am using JSON_ENCODE in PHP to output data.
When it gets to this word: `Æther` it outputs `\u00c6ther`.

Anyone know of a way to make json output that character or am I going to have to change the text to not have that character in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the unicode version of the character. JavaScript should handle it properly. You'll notice the slash before it which means that it's an escape sequence. The `u` indicates it's a unicode code point and the hex digits represent the actual character.
See [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blunicode.htm) for some more info.

Answer (score 3):

That is working as specified. The RFC ( http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt ) indicates that ***any*** character may be escaped, and your average printable character can be written in the `\uXXXX` format.

Any JSON parser that cannot understand a character escaped in that way is not compliant with the standard. Work on resolving that problem rather than trying to coax PHP into misbehaving as well.

(It **is** legal to put UTF-8 characters into JSON strings without escaping them as well, with a few exceptions, but the safe approach of escaping anything questionable is wise.)